# Eslint error, configuration for rule "import/no-cycle" is invalid

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Running my lint script `"lint": "eslint --ext .js ."`, gives me this error:

> Error: .eslintrc » eslint-config-airbnb » //node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/index.js » //node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js:
> Configuration for rule "import/no-cycle" is invalid:
> Value "∞" should be integer.

Package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.2",
    "@babel/parser": "7.11.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "bluebird": "3.7.2",
    "catharsis": "0.8.11",
    "cross-env": "7.0.2",
    "escape-string-regexp": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.8.1",
    "husky": "4.2.3",
    "jest": "25.2.3",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "3.0.3",
    "jest-junit": "10.0.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "2.0.0",
    "js2xmlparser": "4.0.1",
    "jsdoc": "3.6.6",
    "klaw": "3.0.0",
    "markdown-it": "10.0.0",
    "markdown-it-anchor": "5.2.7",
    "marked": "0.8.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "mkdirp": "1.0.4",
    "node": "12.10.0",
    "npm-check": "5.9.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
    "requizzle": "0.2.3",
    "strip-json-comments": "3.1.0",
    "taffydb": "2.6.2",
    "underscore": "1.10.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to this thread https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2331#issuecomment-724114465

you need to update `eslint-plugin-import` to `^2.22.1` which supports `∞` value.

Answer (score 4):

sharing here what i found that resolved this issue.
all the peer dependencies were installed and correct version, however this error was still showing up.

I changed the `node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js` "∞" to an integer to continue debugging.  Next run showed this error, `ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "import" uniquely.`, which was the underlying problem.  it turns out that eslint loads all configs from ancestor directories as described here, https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13385#issuecomment-641252879.

I added `"root":true` to the .eslint config file and converted the update to the `node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js`.  it now runs.  hope it helps others.

Comment: I've tried everything and lost all day trying to fix it but adding `"root":true` to my `.eslintrc.json` fixed it. Thank you!